# Texture is not getting loaded on the object

Tags: javascript, three.js

I am trying to render a 3D model using .obj and .mtl file.The .obj file got rendered successfully but I see no trace of .mtl file, and it's totally not worth to see the object without textures.

I checked the url and all, it's totally fine.
Can anyone help me review the code for any errors

```
objectCall = (el) => {
    this.scene = new THREE.Scene();

    this.camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, el.clientWidth / el.clientHeight, 0.1, 1000000 );
    this.camera.position.z = 2;

    this.renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer({
       canvas: el,
       alpha: true,
       precision: 'highp',
       antialias: true
    });
    this.renderer.setSize( el.clientWidth, el.clientHeight );
    this.renderer.setClearColor(0xfffff, 0)

    this.controls = new OrbitControls(this.camera, el);
    this.controls.target.copy(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0));
    this.controls.enableDamping = true;
    this.controls.dampingFactor = 0.25;
    this.controls.enableZoom = true;

    const keyLight = new THREE.DirectionalLight(new THREE.Color('hsl(30, 100%, 75%)'), 2.512);

     this.camera.add(keyLight);
     const mtlLoader = new MTLLoader();
     console.log(mtlLoader)
     console.log(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${this.props.mtl}`)
     mtlLoader.load(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${this.props.mtl}`, (materials) => {
        materials.preload();
        const objLoader = new OBJLoader();
        console.log('materials',materials)
        objLoader.setMaterials(materials);
        objLoader.load(`https://cors-anywhere.herokuapp.com/${this.props.obj}`, (object) => {
            object.position.copy(new THREE.Vector3(0,0,0))
            this.scene.add(object);
            const box = new THREE.Box3().setFromObject(object);
            const size = box.getSize(new THREE.Vector3());
            const newVec = new THREE.Vector3().copy(box.max).multiplyScalar(1.5);
            newVec.setY(newVec.y + size.y);
            // const newVec = new THREE.Vector3(box.max.x, box.max.y, box.max.z).multiplyScalar(1.5);
            this.camera.position.copy(newVec);
            this.renderer.setAnimationLoop(animate);
        });

    });

    const animate = () => {
      this.controls.update();
      this.renderer.render(this.scene, this.camera);
    };
 }
```

**.mtl file**

```
newmtl BisonPlains_mat
illum 4
Kd 0.50 0.50 0.50
Ka 0.00 0.00 0.00
Tf 1.00 1.00 1.00
Ni 1.00

map_Kd BisonPlains_BaseColor.png
```

**.obj file**

```
# This file uses centimeters as units for non-parametric coordinates.

mtllib BisonPlains.mtl
g default
v 2.460597 11.412973 7.880118
v 2.087346 10.868870 7.778790
.........
```

I am very new to three.js. It will be great if someone can help me overcome the issue

Comment: According to the official `OBJ`/`MTL` example{https://threejs.org/examples/webgl_loader_obj_mtl), your code looks okay. Any chances to share the `OBJ`/`MTL`  files (maybe as a zip)?

Comment: I will update the code wait.

Comment: @Mugen87 I have updated the complete .mtl file and first few lines of .obj.

Comment: Please share the entire files with textures as a zip. Use a service like Google Drive.

Comment: .mtl : - https://drive.google.com/open?id=1Ht_y5vrmX6cojwBGLhtZ14d9kdLdpnYq  .obj : -https://drive.google.com/open?id=17ZfXeJnq7N3LgxYubxx-ylPwvb5tS8LE    Here are the links @Mugen87